# How to use scale in java 2DG

Tags: java, 2d

I am drawing some 2Dgraphics to `JPanel`.
I don't understant how to use scale if i change `JPanel`size?

I have an image, which is composed of multiple lines and circles.
Is possible to compute a transformation and that multiply the values that miscalculation? How? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to do it (but not the best) is to have a final variable for the Width and Height, and everything is calculated based on those variables. then you could have a scale variable that is the size of the (JPanel / final Variable) and when you do g.draw() you can set the width to width * wScale, and the height to height * hScale. here is an example

```
public final WIDTH = 1080;
public final HEIGHT = WIDTH * 16 / 9;

private float wScale = 1;
private float hScale = 1;

public static void mainLoop()
{
    wScale = jpanelWidth / (WIDTH * 1.0);
    hScale = jpanelHeight / (HEIGHT * 1.0);

    //makes the image to draw using the final width and height for calculations
    someclass.makeImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    //gets an image that has the dimentions of WIDTH and HEIGHT
    someimage = someclass.getImage();

    //draws the image using its width and scales it to the actual size by multiplying it by the scaler
    //the two zeros are at position (0, 0), and null is just the observer.
    somegraphics.draw(someimage, 0, 0, (WIDTH * wScale), (HEIGHT * hScale), null);

}
```

if you need more information or have questions, you can ask for clarification, or contact me personally.